# Can I set a custom UICollectionViewLayout in a nib file?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uicollectionview

I've been experimenting with UICollectionViews recently and I'm getting along swimmingly with them so far, no major problems. However, I'm trying to use nib files as much as possible to simplify UI design and changes at a later date in the project, and the one thing I don't seem to be able to do is take a UICollectionView object in a nib and change the default UICollectionFlowLayout object for a different kind of layout object. I'd rather like to do this as it seems wasteful to create an object then immediately replace it in viewDidLoad.

I've tried the usual method of simply selecting the object and changing its type, but it won't allow me to do so with a regular UICollectionViewLayout subclass.

Any ideas? It's not essential, but I'd like to do this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Attributes inspector for the Collection view, you have to change the layout type from "Flow" to "Custom" first. Then you can select your custom `UICollectionViewLayout` class.

[image]